# Auto Layout NSlayoutConstraints with UIVIEW incorrect position

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want  my WKWebview  under a View that has auto layout to 0,0,0,0 to fullscreen of superview.. im also using everything under a navigation controller...

i can't seem to get it right, the WKWebview is showing up like 60 points below . essentially the same height as the status bar with the navigation bar combined..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          println(" daview bounds in viewdidLOAD is \(self.daview.bounds) y Frame \(self.daview.frame)")

        /* Create our preferences on how the web page should be loaded */
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

        /* Create a configuration for our preferences */
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preferences
        /* Now instantiate the web view */
        restWeb = WKWebView(frame:self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
        daview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        restWeb!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        //self.daview.bounds
               //restWeb!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        var urlString:String = ""
        if (DETAILURL != "") { urlString = DETAILURL  }
        else { urlString = "http://www.google.com"  }

        println("EL DETAIL URL es \(urlString)")
        if let theWebView = restWeb {
            println("Existe restWeb")
        let urlRest = NSURL(string:urlString)
        let requestRest = NSURLRequest(URL: urlRest!)
        theWebView.loadRequest(requestRest)
        theWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        theWebView.navigationDelegate = self


        self.daview.addSubview(theWebView)


            let viewsDict = ["view": restWeb,"daview":daview]

            self.daview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[view]-0-|", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views:viewsDict))
            self.daview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))



        }
```